# How to serve a JavaScript file at a specific URI with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I want to publish a JavaScript file exactly at this URI on my Rails server:

```
https://myrailsserver/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js
```

So I put the `yui-min.js` on my Rails server here:

```
[rails-project-root]/public/javascripts/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js
```

Unfortunately, Rails does not serve it at `https://myrailsserver/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js`:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js")
```

How to serve this JavaScript file at this specific path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rails can't find your file at `https://myrailsserver/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js` because you put it into `https://myrailsserver/javascripts/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js`

best

Comment: That's it thanks! I thought `javascripts` was a programming keyword rather than a web path, and I was mislead by Firebug not showing the full path.

Comment: sometimes, the solution is to easy :)